# Swift TableViewの最初のCell表示の位置がおかしい（初期位置が中央になる）

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3, storyboard

下図のように、最初のCellの表示位置がTableの縦方向真ん中から表示されてしまいます。

[image: 最初のCellが縦方向の真ん中に表示されてしまう]

このテーブルに対するコードは以下のコードだけです。
TableViewはStoryboardにおいているだけです。
特にTableViewCellは作成していません。

改善方法を教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblHistory: UITableView!

let cellID = "historyCell"

//テーブルのデータ総数を返す
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView ,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return workContainer.Days.count
}

//指定した行を返す
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: cellID)
    let row:Int = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = DateTimeConv.stringFromDate(date: workContainer.Days[row].Day as NSDate, time: false)
    if workContainer.CountType == true {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(workContainer.IntervalDay)
    }else{
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(workContainer.IntervalToday)
    }
    return cell
}

//セルをタッチして選択した時
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    lblDate.text = DateTimeConv.stringFromDate(date: workContainer.Days[indexPath.row].Day as NSDate, time: false)
    //tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true) //選択解除
}
```

Tableviewの設定
[image: Tableviewの設定値]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StoryboardのUIViewControllerに貼り付けた、UITableViewの位置が真ん中の位置になっていないでしょうか。もしそうであれば、UITableViewをViewController全体に広げて配置すれば上から表示されるのではないかと思います。

Comment: UIViewControllerの上に表示したいサイズでViewを配置して、そのViewにUITableViewをめいっぱい広げて配置したら、期待通りの表示に改善されました。UITableViewだけで表示サイズを決められないんですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: そうですね、UITableViewを画面全体で表示する方法は何通りかありますが、まずはUIView直下にUITableVIewを配置するのがわかりやすくて良いかと思います。（そのあとはAutoLayoutを使って制約をつけてなどありますが、それはまた追々で...）